# The program crashing when trying to open Camera on Thread

Tags: android, android-camera, barcode-scanner

I am trying to freeze the camera preview on a surface view. However I get the error mentioned below.

**My preview class**

```
package com.example.android;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private boolean DEBUG = true;

    private static final String TAG = Preview.class.getSimpleName();

    private static long AUTO_FOCUS_INTERVAL = 1500;

    public static final int CMD_SCAN = 1;

    public static final int CMD_IMAGE_COPIED = 2;

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

    private Handler mHandler;

    Camera mCamera;

    Size mPreviewSize;

    ScanningHandler mPreviewHandler;

    Thread mPreviewThread;

    AtomicBoolean mPreviewThreadRun = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private int angle;

    private Thread mAutofocusThread;

    private Boolean mAutoFocus;

    private byte[] mLastFrameCopy;

    private FrameReceiver mFrameReceiver;

    private Size mFramePreviewSize;

    public interface FrameReceiver {
        public void onFrameReceived(byte[] frameBuffer, Size framePreviewSize);
    }

    public Preview(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public Preview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // this is needed for old android version
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    private Size getOptimalSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.2;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "target view size: " + w + "x" + h + ", target ratio="
                    + targetRatio);

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;
        int targetWidth = w;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            boolean fitToView = size.width <= w && size.height <= h;
            if (DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "Supported preview size: " + size.width + "x"
                        + size.height + ", ratio=" + ratio + ", fitToView="
                        + fitToView);
            if (!fitToView) {
                // we can not use preview size bigger than surface dimensions
                // skipping
                continue;
            }
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) {
                continue;
            }

            double hypot = Math.hypot(size.height - targetHeight, size.width
                    - targetWidth);
            if (hypot < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = hypot;
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            if (DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "Cannot find preview that matchs the aspect ratio, ignore the aspect ratio requirement");

            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (size.width > w || size.height > h) {
                    // we can not use preview size bigger than surface
                    // dimensions
                    continue;
                }

                double hypot = Math.hypot(size.height - targetHeight,
                        size.width - targetWidth);
                if (hypot < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = hypot;
                }
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Unable to determine optimal preview size");
        }
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "optimalSize.width=" + optimalSize.width
                    + ", optimalSize.height=" + optimalSize.height);

        return optimalSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

        if (mCamera == null) {
            if (DEBUG)
                Log.e(TAG, "mCamera == null !");
            return;
        }
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        switch (display.getRotation()) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            angle = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            angle = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            angle = 270;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            angle = 180;
            break;
        default:
            throw new AssertionError("Wrong surface rotation value");
        }
        setDisplayOrientation(params, angle);

        if (mPreviewSize == null) {
            // h and w get inverted on purpose
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalSize(params.getSupportedPreviewSizes(),
                    width > height ? width : height, width > height ? height
                            : width);
        }

        params.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
        if (focusModes != null
                && focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        }

        mCamera.setParameters(params);

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't set preview display", e);
        }

        startPreview();

        mFramePreviewSize = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();

        int bitsPerPixel = 12;
        mLastFrameCopy = new byte[mFramePreviewSize.height
                * mFramePreviewSize.width * bitsPerPixel / 8];
        PreviewCallbackScan();
        mPreviewThreadRun.set(true);
        scan();
    }

    class AutoFocusRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mAutoFocus) {
                if (mCamera != null) {
                    try {
                        mCamera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success,
                                    Camera camera) {
                                mHandler.postDelayed(AutoFocusRunnable.this,
                                        AUTO_FOCUS_INTERVAL);
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to auto-focus", e);
                        mHandler.postDelayed(AutoFocusRunnable.this,
                                AUTO_FOCUS_INTERVAL);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    };

    void startAutofocus() {
        mAutoFocus = true;
        mAutofocusThread = new Thread(new AutoFocusRunnable(),
                "Autofocus Thread");
        mAutofocusThread.start();
    }

    void stopPreview() {
        mAutoFocus = false;
        if (mCamera != null)
            mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
        mAutofocusThread = null;
        if (mCamera != null)
            mCamera.stopPreview();
    }

    void startPreview() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.startPreview();
            startAutofocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mCamera == null) {
            try {
                mCamera = Camera.open();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getContext(),
                        "Unable to connect to camera. "
                                + "Perhaps it's being used by another app.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        if (mCamera != null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void setDisplayOrientation(Camera.Parameters params, int angle) {
        try {
            Method method = mCamera.getClass().getMethod(
                    "setDisplayOrientation", new Class[] { int.class });
            if (method != null)
                method.invoke(mCamera, new Object[] { angle });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "Can't call Camera.setDisplayOrientation on this device, trying another way");
            if (angle == 90 || angle == 270)
                params.set("orientation", "portrait");
            else if (angle == 0 || angle == 180)
                params.set("orientation", "landscape");
        }
        params.setRotation(angle);
    }

    public class PreviewThread extends Thread {

        public PreviewThread(String string) {
            super(string);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
            mPreviewHandler = new ScanningHandler();
            Looper.loop();
        };
    }

    public void setFrameReceiver(FrameReceiver receiver) {
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "set Frame Receiver");
        mFrameReceiver = receiver;

    }

    private Object mLastFrameCopyLock = new Object();

    public void copyLastFrame(byte[] frame) {

        synchronized (mLastFrameCopyLock) {
            if (DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "copying frame");
            System.arraycopy(frame, 0, mLastFrameCopy, 0, frame.length);
        }
        mPreviewHandler.obtainMessage(CMD_IMAGE_COPIED).sendToTarget();
    }

    public byte[] getLastFrameCopy() {

        synchronized (mLastFrameCopyLock) {
            return mLastFrameCopy;
        }
    }

    public void scan() {
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "<<<<<<<<<<<<<< scan called >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        removeAllMessages();
        mPreviewHandler.obtainMessage(CMD_SCAN).sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * @return the default angle of the camera
     */

    public int getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    public void PreviewCallbackScan() {

        mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                if (data == null) {
                    return;
                }
                copyLastFrame(data);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ScanningHandler extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {

            case (CMD_SCAN):
                if (mPreviewThreadRun.get()) {
                    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mLastFrameCopy);
                    break;
                }
                break;

            case (CMD_IMAGE_COPIED):
                if (mPreviewThreadRun.get()) {
                    if (DEBUG)
                        Log.d(TAG, "frame copied");
                    mFrameReceiver.onFrameReceived(getLastFrameCopy(),
                            mFramePreviewSize);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public void removeAllMessages() {
        mPreviewHandler.removeMessages(CMD_SCAN);
        mPreviewHandler.removeMessages(CMD_IMAGE_COPIED);
    }

}




**DemoActivity**


package com.example.android;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.YuvImage;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.moodstocks.android.MoodstocksError;
import com.moodstocks.android.Result;
import com.moodstocks.android.ScannerSession;
import com.moodstocks.android.core.CameraManager;

public class ScanActivity extends Activity implements CameraManager.Listener,
        ScannerSession.Listener, View.OnClickListener,
        ProgressDialog.OnCancelListener {

    // -----------------------------------
    // Interface implemented by overlays
    // -----------------------------------
    public static interface Listener {
        /* send a new result to Overlay */
        public void onResult(ScannerSession session, Result result);

        /* send any other information in a Bundle */
        public void onStatusUpdate(Bundle status);
    }

    private AlertDialog ad;

    // private QueryProgressDialog pd;

    private AtomicBoolean activityRunning = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private Preview.FrameReceiver mreceiver;

    private WebView webViewer;

    // Enabled scanning types: configure it according to your needs.
    // Here we allow Image recognition, EAN13, Datamatrix and QRCodes decoding.
    // Feel free to add `EAN8` if you want in addition to decode EAN-8.
    private int ScanOptions = Result.Type.IMAGE | Result.Type.EAN13
            | Result.Type.QRCODE | Result.Type.DATAMATRIX;

    public static final String TAG = "Main";
    private ScannerSession session;
    private Overlay overlay;
    private View touch;
    private Bundle status;
    private ProgressDialog searching;
    static final boolean DEBUG = true;

    // Activates the local search.
    static final boolean SEARCH_OBJECT_LOCAL = false;

    // Activates the barcode scanning
    static boolean SEARCH_OBJECT_BARCODE = true;

    // Activates the scan search.
    static boolean SEARCH_OBJECT_SCAN = true;

    // Activates the snap search
    static boolean SEARCH_OBJECT_SNAP = true;

    // Activates the remote search.
    static final boolean SEARCH_OBJECT_REMOTE = true;

    private Handler handler;

    private Preview preview;

    Camera Camera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        preview.mPreviewThread = preview.new PreviewThread("Preview Thread");
        preview.mPreviewThread.start();

        // initialize the overlay, that will display results and informations
        overlay = (Overlay) findViewById(R.id.overlay);
        overlay.init();
        // initialize the tap-on-screen
        touch = findViewById(R.id.touch);
        touch.setOnClickListener(this);
        // get the camera preview surface
        SurfaceView preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);

        // Create a scanner session
        try {
            session = new ScannerSession(this, this, preview);
        } catch (MoodstocksError e) {
            e.log();
        }
        // set session options
        // session.setOptions(ScanOptions);
         mreceiver = new DemoFrameReceiver();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        activityRunning.set(true);

        // start scanning!
        // session.resume();
        // preview.setFrameReceiver(mreceiver);
        // Send information to the overlay
        status = new Bundle();
        status.putBoolean("decode_ean_8", (ScanOptions & Result.Type.EAN8) != 0);
        status.putBoolean("decode_ean_13",
                (ScanOptions & Result.Type.EAN13) != 0);
        status.putBoolean("decode_qrcode",
                (ScanOptions & Result.Type.QRCODE) != 0);
        status.putBoolean("decode_datamatrix",
                (ScanOptions & Result.Type.DATAMATRIX) != 0);
        overlay.onStatusUpdate(status);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        session.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        session.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (overlay.result != null) {
            overlay.onResult(session, null);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    // -------------------------
    // ScannerSession.Listener
    // -------------------------

    @Override
    public void onScanComplete(Result result) {
        if (result != null) {
            // pause scanning session
            session.pause();
            // result found, send to overlay
            overlay.onResult(session, result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(MoodstocksError error) {
        // in this sample code, we just log the errors.
        error.log();
    }

    @Override
    public void onApiSearchStart() {
        // inform user
        searching = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Searching...", true, true,
                this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onApiSearchComplete(Result result) {
        searching.dismiss();
        if (result != null) {
            // pause scanning session
            session.pause();
            // result found, send to overlay
            overlay.onResult(session, result);
        } else {
            // no result found, inform user
            Toast t = Toast
                    .makeText(this, "No match found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 200);
            t.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onApiSearchFailed(MoodstocksError e) {
        searching.dismiss();
        // A problem occurred, e.g. there is no available network. Inform user:
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 200);
        t.show();
    }

    // ----------------------
    // View.OnClickListener
    // ----------------------

    // Intercept tap-on-screen:
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == touch) {
            // session.resume();
        }
    }

    private void stopScanning() {
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "stop scanning");
        preview.mPreviewThreadRun.set(false);
    }

    // ---------------------------------
    // ProgressDialog.OnCancelListener
    // ---------------------------------

    // User cancelled snap
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        if (dialog == this.searching) {
            session.cancel();
        }
    }

    private void freezePreview() {
        // on old device freezing preview only shows a black screen
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "preview is freezed");
        preview.stopPreview();
        preview.PreviewCallbackScan();
    }

    private void processImageScan(final YuvImage yuv) {
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "scan decode message");
        // iqe.goScan();
        // Message.obtain(iqe, IQE.CMD_DECODE, IQE.scan, 0, yuv).sendToTarget();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewInfoFound(int w, int h, boolean front_facing) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraOpenFailed(int e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    class DemoFrameReceiver implements Preview.FrameReceiver {

        /**
         * Starts the continuous local search with the displayed frames.
         * 
         * @param frameBuffer
         *            A {@link Byte} array, the frame's data.
         * @param framePreviewSize
         *            A {@link Size}, the frame dimensions.
         */

        @Override
        public void onFrameReceived(byte[] frameBuffer, Size framePreviewSize) {

            if (!preview.mPreviewThreadRun.get()) {
                return;
            }

            if (frameBuffer == null) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "no picture");
                return;
            }

            YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(frameBuffer, 17,
                    framePreviewSize.width, framePreviewSize.height, null);
            // analyze the picture.
            processImageScan(yuvImage);

        }

    }

}
```

ErrorLog:

```
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.ScanActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at com.example.android.ScanActivity.onCreate(ScanActivity.java:93)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5195)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
10-11 16:21:25.429: E/AndroidRuntime(4441):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Which line is `ScanActivity.java:93`?

Comment: format ur logcat code. which is the line 93 in onCreate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is the infamous `ScanActivity line 93`.-

```
preview.mPreviewThread = preview.new PreviewThread("Preview Thread");
```

You're trying to access `preview` variable without initializing it, which throws the `NullPointerException`.